# iOS Container view. Load view controllers dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using storyboards. I have main view controller with 2 Container views on in. In first Container view I have view controller with 2 buttons. In second Container view I have view controller with some label.

Question: how can I switch view controller instance in second Container view? When I click on button from Container view 1 I want to change view controller on Container view 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask your question clearly!!!. You've main view  controller , it have two view corresponding to two view controllers. First view have two buttons , and second view has label, When you click on button which is place on first view, you've to change label status which is placed on secondview. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Mani, thanks for commenting here. Unfortunately you didn't get me right. I want to change the view controller in second container view, not to update already placed view controller.

Comment: @VenelinSpiridonov In the button action handler of the button you click, remove the view that is currently added on the 2nd container view, add another view. You are facing any problem doing that?

Comment: @Adithya, I would like to replace the view controller, not only one view. It seems that I need to replace the inner MVC, because I will use different model, views and so one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the **Adding and Removing a child** section of this [Apple Docs link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13). It explains the steps required to add and remove the child view controller from a parent view controller.

Comment: Updated the link to Apple Docs

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `prepareForSegue:` method. This will allow you to get a reference to the `viewController` about to be pushed. So you could do something like this from your Main View Controller.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewController_2"]) {
      [[segue.destinationViewController myTextLabel] setText:@"SomeText"];
   }
}
```

You can use `segue.destinationViewController` to access variables in the viewController about to be pushed. You might need to type cast the destinationViewController which can be done like this.

```
[(MyController *)segue.destinationViewController myLabel]
```